# How to NDSolve this kind of ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics

For an ODE like this:$(1-y)y'+y^2=0$ with the initial condition $y(1)=1$, how to solve it numerically? I know this equation can be solved analytically by `DSolve`. In fact, my equation is more complicated than this, I have to solve it numerically. Using `NDSolve` directly,

```
NDSolve[{(1 - y[x])*y'[x] + y[x]^2 == 0, y[1] == 1}, y, {x, 1, 5}]
```

it will display error messages:

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 1.`.
```

I guess this problem happens because the initial condition just makes the coefficient of `y'[x]` be zero.  So my question is how to overcome this problem?

Comment: The derivative diverges at the point $x=1$, and it's hard to deal with divergencies numerically. Perturbing the initial condition slightly removes the problem, e.g. `NDSolve[{(1 - y[x])*y'[x] + y[x]^2 == 0, y[1] == 1.01}, y, {x, 1, 5}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can here introduce another dependent variable: `z[x]->y[x] - y[x]^2/2`and express your equation in terms of this variable:

```
    ss = NDSolve[{z'[x] + (1 - Sqrt[1 - 2 z[x]])^2 == 0, z[1] == 1/2}, 
       z[x], {x, 1, 10}][[1, 1]]
(*  z[x] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 10.}}, <>][x]  *)
```

which is nicely solved:

```
Plot[1 - Sqrt[1 - 2 z[x]] /. ss, {x, 1, 10}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 18, Italic], Style["y", 18, Italic]}]
```

yielding

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: This transformation actually will lead to 2 equations: `((1 - y[x])*y'[x] + y[x]^2 == 0 /. Solve[z[x] == y[x] - y[x]^2/2, y[x]] /. (y[x] -> a_) :> (y -> (Function[x, #] &@a)))`, which correspond to 2 solutions of the original equation :)

Comment: @ xzczd  of course, but since this is evident, the OP can figure it out himself and decide, what solution is he interested in.

Answer (score 6):

Your specific example is actually special, it has 2 solutions, and `DSolve` can only find one of them. To find both of the solutions, we can modify the equation from a equation of $y(x)$ to a equation of $x(y)$:

$$\frac{1-y}{x'(y)}+y^2=0$$

Then `DSolve` and `NDSolve` can both handle the equation without difficulty:

```
asolinverse = x /. First@DSolve[{(1 - y)*1/x'[y] + y^2 == 0, x[1] == 1}, x, y]
(* Function[{y}, (1 + y Log[y])/y] *)
nsolinverse = 
 x /. First@NDSolve[{(1 - y)*1/x'[y] + y^2 == 0, x[1] == 1}, x, {y, 10^-3, 100}]

ParametricPlot[{nsolinverse[y], y}, {y, 10^-3, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: your method is also very good. But I think Boulbitch's method is more universal. For more complicated ODEs, it is not easy to modify the equation from an equation of y(x) to an equation of x(y) .